# How do I more easily reskin iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode, dependencies, skinning

I have a base app that I reskin for multiple customers, but I am trying to find a better way to do it. Currently I have a separate project for each of them. However, I have learned that there is a way in android to do this more easily and I would like to do it for iOS/Xcode. For android there is a main project that is all of the coding for the app, and then there is a secondary project that just has a list of strings that overwrites the main project giving it the proper graphics for that skin.

I hope that makes sense. If not then I will try to explain better.

Does anyone know of a similar way to work that out in Xcode/iOS?

Comment: You could try using different targets of one project and associating different groups of resources, but the same codebase.

Comment: Great idea. Forgive my ignorance, but how would I associate different groups of resources?

Comment: Never mind. It was more obvious than I was realizing. Thanks for the idea @IanMacDonald

Comment: No worries. I hope it works out for you!

Comment: @IanMacDonald I am trying to do this, but having a couple issues. Do I need to have all classes to the main project included in the other targets? Including the prefix and appdelegate and such?

Comment: If you choose your original target and select "duplicate", it will do most of the heavy lifting for you. After that, you just need to associate your different set of resources in the target build phases.

Comment: @IanMacDonald that seems to have done the trick. I would like to give you credit for the answer, so if you want to write it up in a way that I could do that, it would me much appreciated. Thanks